# Is it possible to load a particular range of a serialized python dictonary from hard disk?

Tags: python, data-structures, pickle

I have a very huge dictionary that is serialized in the hard disk. I don't have enough memory to load it completely in memory. I need to read only a particular range of the dictionary (say 100th - 200th element in the dictionary).

Is it possible to load only these elements from the file? Note that the keys and values of the dictionary are strings.

Comment: Not easily - you'd need to implement your own unpickler that can filter the items you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how did you serialize the data? (pickle/json/...)

also note that elements in a dictionary are not sorted (except if you used a `collections.OrderedDict`). so retrieving a range of elements may not give what you expect.

if the amount of data you are trying to handle exceeds the memory wouldn't it be better to use some kind of database? if your data is a dict, something like `shelve` or `redis` might be appropriate.

Comment: 1. I used a pickle to serialize the dict. 2. It is OK for me to get the samples even if they are unordered. 3. Thanks for the suggestion regarding database but there is no database availablity right now. 4. Let me look at shelve and redis - Thanks.